# Python Webbrowser Opening URLs with Chrome instead of IE

Tags: python, google-chrome, webbrowser-control, python-webbrowser

I've been attempting to create a function that iterates over inputs from a text file that contains URLs, using `webbrowser` package. It works fine when I create a empty list to which URLs are literally appended, as in:

```
import webbrowser

list = []
list.append(url1)
list.append(url2)
def webbrowsing(list)
   for i in range(0, len(list)):
     webbrowser.open(list[i])
```

where url1 and url2 are any valid URLs. And `webbrowser.open()` opens the URLs in Chrome and it is really good.

However, when I try and do the same thing with inputs from a text file of URLs, webbrowser opens the URLs from the file in **Internet Explorer**. I gave it a try using `webbrowser.get()`, explicitly directing it to use Chrome, but that didn't work.
I am not very sure **why it does not open the URLs in Chrome**, when almost everything seems the same as when the list is used as mentioned above. Chrome is set as my default web browser, and I rarely use the IE. I'd really appreciate any tips on that issue.

Answer (score 0):

How do you define the 'webbrowser' object? I use something like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverPath) #driverPath contains the path to the 'chromedriver.exe' file
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: I start with "import webbrowser" to enable the module 'webbrowser.' Webdriver is another module, isn't it?

Comment: yes, it's Selenium
`from selenium import webdriver`

Comment: Thank you. Have you every used the Webbrowser module? I think I spotted a possible cause that leads to IE... I put "site:" as a string before the URLs, just to see whether I can do within-a-website search. Do you have any idea why "site:" cannot be used with chrome though it works when you use it on a web browser?

Comment: Don't have any, sorry (( Haven't ever used Webbrowser module. May be it is not the same thing when you use some string argument in browser's url field and whet you us it as an argument in the module's object

Comment: Thanks heaps! I'll look into the issue a bit more and at the same time see what I can do with selenium too.

Comment: Ryusuke: you had to add the missing `import`, to make your code reproducible (MCVE). Otherwise, Python has tons of packages, and `webbrowser` could have been instantiated or imported from hundreds of things.